# firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() concat with string val

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

As per Firebase documentation, we should not use incremental values as it may cause hotspots.
I have multiple subcollections and I am only interested in ordering my subcollection, so I want to concat server-side timestamp with a document ID (which represents the document inside which my subcollection exist)

But as the serverside time stamp is calculated at the server level, how can I do it?

Comment: You can't - if you must use a server timestamp, you can only write that value to a field by itself using the server timestamp token in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am having multiple subcollections and I am only interested in ordering my subcollections.

You cannot order subcollections. According to the docs, the [ordering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) refers to documents and **not** to collections or subcollections.

> I want to concat server-side timestamp with a document ID.

You can choose to name the subcollections any way you want, but you won't find a function that will order them.

> But as the serverside timestamp is calculated at the server level, how can I do it?

As @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, if you need to use a server timestamp, then you have to write that value to a field (of the document) using the server timestamp token in your application's code.